# How to disable XML external entity (XXE) processing in JAXP 1.1/Java 1.4?

Tags: java, xml, owasp, jaxp, java1.4

I'm working on making sure some code isn't vulnerable to XXE attacks.  For stuff being compiled and run on Java 7 and Java 8 I've had success with OWASP's recommendations -- see the Java section of https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Processing

Here's the relevant snippet, trimmed down:

```
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

  String FEATURE = "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl";
  dbf.setFeature(FEATURE, true);

  FEATURE = "http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities";
  dbf.setFeature(FEATURE, false);

  FEATURE = "http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities";
  dbf.setFeature(FEATURE, false);

  dbf.setXIncludeAware(false);
  dbf.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
```

However, there's also (sigh) a Java 1.4 version of the code in question that needs to be fixed.  But in Java 1.4 the `DocumentBuilderFactory` class does **not** have a `setFeature()` method, so this approach would appear to be inapplicable.

I have spent some time searching, but there's not much left out there on Java 1.4/JAXP 1.1 processing and even when things are found, links within the documents are often dead.  So far I haven't managed to find how to disable XXE in Java 1.4 and so am asking here.